# GETDATE () - 1 on SSIS

Tags: ssis

I created a variable in SSIS, but it doesn't accept GETDATE () -1

```
REPLACE( @[User::FilePath] , ".xls","" )+"_" +  (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) +".xls"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do here, identify what yesterday's date was?

Comment: yes, I want to identify yesterday's date.
thank you.

Comment: Select cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) as date)

Comment: Using `GETDATE() - 1` is poor programming practice. You should use `DATEADD()` and explicitly define the operation.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to create multiple variables. The problem you have right now is that you can't set a breakpoint on an SSIS expression to try and debug the thing.

### Yesterday

[DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/dateadd-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
dateadd("day", -1, getdate())
```

Test, evaluate and ensure it's working as intended

### Yesterday_CCYYMMDD

This will be the text string of the Yesterday variable (20191212)

```
(DT_WSTR,4) YEAR(@[User::Yesterday]) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(@[User::Yesterday])) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(@[User::Yesterday]))
```

### YesterdayFileName

Finally, chain it all together

```
REPLACE( @[User::FilePath], ".xls", "") + @[User::YesterdayFileName] + ".xls"
```